# Unable to run i386-elf-gcc

Tags: gcc, x86, cross-compiling, arch

When installing i386-elf-gcc using aur. Install goes smoothly and no errors when I build. I added `/usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin` to my path and I am able to run the command. When I run a simple command such as `i386-elf-gcc -g "kernel.cpp" -o "kernel.o"`, I am getting errors:

```
/usr/local/i386elfgcc/lib/gcc/i386-elf/10.2.0/../../../../i386-elf/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
/usr/local/i386elfgcc/lib/gcc/i386-elf/10.2.0/../../../../i386-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lg
/usr/local/i386elfgcc/lib/gcc/i386-elf/10.2.0/../../../../i386-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

Reinstalling has not worked. What can I do to fix this? I am using Arch.

Comment: Does it come with any instructions about adding library path environment variables?  Also, standard AUR usage will normally make a `.pkg` file you can install, which should get things added to any necessary paths.  Are you trying to use it from its build directory without installing the `.pkg`, or did you choose this path when building via AUR?

Comment: I did yay i386-elf-gcc and just installed. Should I download PKGBUILD and do that instead?

Comment: Shouldn't you be building this as freestanding (compile with `-ffreestanding` since the C runtime and C library won't be available in your kernel unless you provide your own?

Comment: The entire command I use is ```i386-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -g "kernel.cpp" -o "kernel.o"``` but even with that I get the errors

Comment: what if you add `-nostdlib` (since you are compiling and linking all in one step which is a bit unusual. Usually you compile with `-c` to generate `.o` files and then link those to a final executable.

Comment: It works! Can you explain why?

Comment: Because when linking by default the cross compiler is still assuming that there are C libraries and C runtimes available. That doesn't happen to be the case, which is why `-nostdlib` exists. `-nostdlib` will tell the linker that it shouldn't include the C runtime or C startup files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original command was `i386-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -g "kernel.cpp" -o "kernel.o"`
I needed to add `-nostdlib`

Final command:
`i386-elf-gcc -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m32 -g "kernel.cpp" -o "kernel.o"`

Comment: It is also a bit peculiar to have CPP (C++) files processed with GCC. If you are using C++ you'd compile with G++. If all your code is straight C then I'd rename `.cpp` to `.c`.

Comment: `i386-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -g "kernel.cpp" -o "kernel.o"` doesn't create an object file called `kernel.o`. It creates an ELF executable called `kernel.o`. You should be using the `-c` option to compile `.c` files to `.o` then use GCC (or LD directly) to link all the object files to an ELF executable